# How to use two model classes in one view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor

I have got Category and VehicleRegistration classes. I don't know how to use both classes in view. I want to show property names and values like Name, Manufacturer, Year, Icon on the page. I tried several methods like Tuple and ViewModel. They didn't work for me. Thanks in advance!

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Vehicle_Details.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int MinValue { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int MaxValue { get; set; }

        /*[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[/]+[a-zA-Z0-9""'\s-]*$")]*/
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Icon { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9""'\s-]*$")]
        [StringLength(20)]
        private string type;
        public string Type
        {
            get
            {
                return type;
            }
            set
            {
               type = value;
            }
        }

        public bool IsValid()
        {
            return this.MinValue.CompareTo(this.MaxValue) <= 0;
        }
        public bool ContainsValue(int value)
        {
            return (this.MinValue.CompareTo(value) <= 0) && (value.CompareTo(this.MaxValue) <= 0);
        }

        public bool IsInsideRange(Category category)
        {
            return this.IsValid() &&  category.IsValid() && category.ContainsValue(this.MinValue) && category.ContainsValue(this.MaxValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Another class is VehicleRegistration

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Vehicle_Details.Models
{
    public class VehicleRegistration
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Manufactuer Manufacturer { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Year { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$")]
        public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I wanted to show data on VehicleRegistration/Index.cshtml, I've hardcoded the Icon and image in this class. The icon property under Category class should show different car size images value based on its weight.

```
Enumerable<Vehicle_Details.Models.VehicleRegistration> 
        
        @{
            ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
        }

        <h1>Index</h1>

        <p>
            <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
        </p>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Manufacturer)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Year)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Icon
                       @* @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Weight)*@
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Manufacturer)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="/images/small.PNG" width="70" height="70" />
                            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Weight)*@

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I want it to look like this

[image: Please click on this link]

Currently, it looks like this. If don't change the code.

[image: Please click on this link]

Comment: Show the several methods you tried that didn't work

Comment: I think the code provided isn't enough information to get help. There is a `blazor` tag, so I don't think the link is helpful...

Comment: Hi John, I've already read that post before. But it didn't work for me.Cheers

Comment: How and where do you want to show the data from the objects?

Comment: Hi there, I wanted to show the data on VehicleRegistration/Index.cshtml, I only want to change the last property from weight to Icon and show the image of the car rather than its weight. I saved image url in the Icon property under the Category class model.

Comment: How is the Category class related to the VehicleRegistration class? To put it briefly, you have to have some kind of way of looking up the category for a given vehicle. Typically this is done using an ORM like Entity Framework or Stack Exchange's own Dapper, which would relate entities together and fill them in for you. In either case, a VehicleRegistration would have a Category property of type Category, from which you could reference the Icon. If you don't have that via an ORM, you'll have to do it manually. It's not terribly difficult, but there has to be some mechanism for relating them.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Can someone please give me an example using an ORM Entity Framework? I am using a .NET Core web application in C#.

Comment: Hi @Rajvir Kaur, What is the relationship between Category and VehicleRegistration ? One-to-many or one-to-one or many-to-many? For your scenario, just define the relationship and it will be easier display two models.